# Efficient daemon in Vala

Tags: performance, daemon, vala

i'd like to make a daemon in Vala which only executes a task every X seconds.
I was wondering which would be the best way:

1. Thread.usleep() or Posix.sleep()
2. GLib.MainLoop + GLib.Timeout
3. other?

I don't want it to eat too many resources when it's doing nothing..

Comment: Out of curiosity: what kind of task is this if cron can't handle it?

Comment: Changing the wallpaper..i know there's plenty of wallpaper changers out there,but i wanted to make one myself and was wondering about how the best way would be.

Comment: Well, I don't think there's that much of a difference; every solution will probably at one point or another call the system sleep() anyway, so I'd go with a timout because it's convenient to do with the signal handler..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you spend your time sleeping in a system call, there's won't be any appreciable difference from a performance perspective. That said, it probably makes sense to use the MainLoop approach for two reasons:

1. You're going to need to setup signal handlers so that your daemon can die instantaneously when it is given SIGTERM. If you call `quit` on your main loop by binding `SIGTERM` via `Posix.signal`, that's probably going to be a more readable piece of code than checking that the sleep was successful.
2. If you ever decide to add complexity, the MainLoop will make it more straight forward.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `GLib.Timeout.add_seconds` the following way:

```
Timeout.add_seconds (5000, () => {
  /* Do what you want here */

  // Continue this "loop" every 5000 ms
  return Source.CONTINUE;

  // Or remove it
  return Source.REMOVE;
}, Priority.LOW);
```

**Note**: The Timeout is set as Priority.LOW as it runs in background and should give priority to others tasks.

Comment: For something like this you probably want to use `GLib.Timeout.add_seconds`, not `add`, especially since the question was originally asked with an eye toward performance.

Comment: @nemequ thanks for the info, just updated the sample ;)